# Android instrumentation tests failed with ''java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError' Empty test suite.'

Tags: java, android, android-espresso, android-instrumentation

After I added `testCoverageEnabled = true` to `debug` build type my instrumentation tests start failing with message `Started running tests
Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError'
Empty test suite.`
What is strange with `testCoverageEnabled = false` everything works.

here is my `build.gradle`

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.21.7'
        classpath 'io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.0.0'

        // https://github.com/JakeWharton/hugo
        classpath 'com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-plugin:1.2.1'
        // https://github.com/stanfy/spoon-gradle-plugin
        classpath('com.stanfy.spoon:spoon-gradle-plugin:1.2.0') {
            exclude module: 'guava'
        }
        classpath 'com.google.guava:guava:20.0'
        // https://github.com/zsoltk/paperwork
        classpath 'hu.supercluster:paperwork-plugin:1.2.7'

        // https://github.com/android10/frodo
        classpath "com.fernandocejas.frodo:frodo-plugin:0.8.3"
    }
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'findbugs'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
apply plugin: 'spoon'
apply plugin: 'android-command'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.hugo'
apply plugin: 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount'
apply plugin: 'hu.supercluster.paperwork'
apply plugin: 'permission'
apply plugin: 'com.fernandocejas.frodo'
apply plugin: "me.tatarka.retrolambda"
apply from: './jacoco.gradle'

int minSdk = project.hasProperty('minSdk') ? minSdk.toInteger() : 18 //Android 4.3 (Look into gradle.properties for actual value)

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url 'https://github.com/uPhyca/stetho-realm/raw/master/maven-repo' }
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

paperwork {
    set = [
            gitSha   : gitSha(),
            buildDate: buildTime("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:00 z", "UTC"),
    ]
}

frodo {
    enabled = true
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    dataBinding {
        enabled true
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        minSdkVersion minSdk
        targetSdkVersion 24
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        versionCode 12
        versionName "1.4"
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.mobile.TestAppAndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            minifyEnabled false
            testCoverageEnabled = true
            debuggable = true;
            ext.enableCrashlytics = false

            buildConfigField "boolean", "DISABLE_CRASHLITYCS", "true"
        }

        rc {
            initWith(release)
            applicationIdSuffix ".rc"
            versionNameSuffix "-rc"

            debuggable true

            buildConfigField "boolean", "DISABLE_CRASHLITYCS", "false"
            ext.enableCrashlytics = true

            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            testCoverageEnabled false
            buildConfigField "boolean", "DISABLE_CRASHLITYCS", "false"
            ext.enableCrashlytics = true

            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        internal {
            applicationIdSuffix = ".internal"
        }
        production {
        }
    }

    // Remove internalRelease as it's not needed.
    android.variantFilter { variant ->
        if (variant.buildType.name.equals('release')
                && variant.getFlavors().get(0).name.equals('internal')) {
            variant.setIgnore(true)
        } else if (variant.buildType.name.equals('rc')
                && variant.getFlavors().get(0).name.equals('internal')) {
            variant.setIgnore(true)
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests {
            // returnDefaultValues = true was added to avoid an error while calling Application.onCreate in Unit test:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support#TOC-Method-...-not-mocked.-
            returnDefaultValues = true
            all {
                testLogging {
                    exceptionFormat = 'full'
                    events "passed", "skipped", "failed", "standardOut", "standardError"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        // excluding to avoid DuplicateFileException
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.google.dagger/dagger/pom.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.google.dagger/dagger/pom.xml'
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.google.guava/guava/pom.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.google.guava/guava/pom.xml'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.res.srcDirs = [
                'src/main/res',

                // component resources
                'src/main/res_components/customization',
                'src/main/res_components/daily',
                'src/main/res_components/external',
                'src/main/res_components/leaflet',
                'src/main/res_components/more',
                'src/main/res_components/onboarding',
                'src/main/res_components/search',
                'src/main/res_components/scanner',
                'src/main/res_components/treatments',
                'src/main/res_components/treatment',
                'src/main/res_components/treatment_plan',
                'src/main/res_components/wizard'
        ]
    }
}

dependencies {
    //tooltips
    compile project(':calendar')
    compile project(':tooltips')

    // dependency injection
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.7'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.7'
    provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'

    // icepick
    compile 'frankiesardo:icepick:3.2.0'
    annotationProcessor 'frankiesardo:icepick-processor:3.2.0'

    // reactive java
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'

    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.4.2'


    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.4.1'
    compile 'com.uphyca:stetho_realm:2.0.0'


    // rest client
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.6.0'

    // material design support libraries
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:transition:25.2.0'

    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    // Barcode scanning
    // You can add javadoc it is located in app/libs/docs
    compile(name: 'CortexDecoderLibrary', ext: 'aar')

    // multidex
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    // permissions
    compile 'com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher:2.1.3'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher-processor:2.1.3'

    // tools
    provided 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.14'
    annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.14"
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.1.2'
    compile 'hu.supercluster:paperwork:1.2.7'

    // time --- JSR-310 backport --- https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP
    compile 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.0.3'

    // graphics
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    // UI
    compile('com.mikepenz:fastadapter:2.1.6@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.mikepenz:fastadapter-commons:2.1.0@aar'
    compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.8.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile('com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:2.0.2') {
        exclude module: 'design'
    }
    compile 'com.github.lsjwzh.RecyclerViewPager:lib:v1.1.0'
    // number picker
    compile 'com.shawnlin:number-picker:2.0.1'
    // date picker
    compile 'com.code-troopers.betterpickers:library:3.0.1'

    // XML schema validation TODO replace with something smaller
    compile files('libs/xerces-for-android.jar')

    // tracking
    compile "com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.9.2"

    // fabric
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.7@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    //debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.4-beta2'
    debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta2'
    rcCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta2'
    releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta2'
    testCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta2'

    // Dependencies for unit test
    testAnnotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.7'
    testCompile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.7'
    testCompile 'com.github.fabioCollini:DaggerMock:0.6.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.5'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.5'
    testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:1.6.5"
    testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-classloading-xstream:1.6.5"
    testCompile 'com.google.truth:truth:0.28'
    testCompile 'com.google.guava:guava:20.0'
    // fallback to standard JVM time backport for unit testing
    testCompile 'org.threeten:threetenbp:1.3.2'
    // Barcode scanning
    // You can add javadoc it is located in app/libs/docs
    testCompile(name: 'CortexDecoderLibrary', ext: 'aar')

    // Robolectric
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.1.2'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:shadows-core:3.1.2'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:shadows-multidex:3.1.2'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:shadows-support-v4:3.1.2'

    // workaround for missing opengl
    testCompile 'org.khronos:opengl-api:gl1.1-android-2.1_r1'

    // Network
    testCompile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:3.6.0'

    // Android Testing Support Library's runner and rules
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'

    androidTestAnnotationProcessor  'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.7'
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.7'

    // Dependencies for Android unit tests
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'

    // --- fixed 1.4 version | allows using MockAnnotations again ---
    // https://github.com/crittercism/dexmaker/pull/24
    androidTestCompile "com.github.crittercism.dexmaker:dexmaker-parent:f8e7c23e4172af8767758c99c9165dd2bd4f0e7f"
    androidTestCompile("com.github.crittercism.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:f8e7c23e4172af8767758c99c9165dd2bd4f0e7f") {
        exclude group: 'mockito'
    }
    androidTestCompile "com.github.crittercism.dexmaker:dexmaker-dx:f8e7c23e4172af8767758c99c9165dd2bd4f0e7f"
    androidTestCompile "com.github.crittercism.dexmaker:dexmaker:f8e7c23e4172af8767758c99c9165dd2bd4f0e7f"
    // ---

    // Espresso Ui Testing
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude group: 'javax.inject'
    })
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-web:2.2.2'

    // Resolve conflicts between main and test APK:
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.2.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
}

configurations {
    androidTestCompile.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding following lines in `app/build.gradle`

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets', 'src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/fonts']
        java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/instrumentTest', 'src/instrumentTest/java', 'src/test/java']
    }
    test {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/test/java', 'src/test/java/']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src/test/resources']
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but unfortunately didn't helped

Comment: Test classes must be placed under app/src/test/java.

Comment: Test classes must extend ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2

Comment: Here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.html is said that it is deprecated